# backup options for Stack Overflow Careers Profile

Tags: discussion, jobs

Now that I invested *some* effort into composing my [Careers profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv) I began wondering how could I **[backup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup)** it for the case of eventual data loss?

- Did it happened to you that you clicked that *little red cross* near the book or article that you carefully selected, strategically placed in the list and thoroughly summarized? It happened to me at careers. *Once.* After that I decided to take care of making a backup.

Solution I use now looks as follows:
1. open [Profile -> Employer](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/employer) view
2. click through all the *display more...* links to expand lists
3. in browser (FF) click through *File -> Save Page As... -> Web Page, complete*

I wonder if there's a better way to do stuff like that?

I wonder in particular if there's sort of *time machine* that would keep step-by-step track for all the changes I do to careers profile. So that I could for example click *contact us* link, send a mail asking to recover the state of profile as it was, say on Aug 26, 2011 and get it done?

Comment: Backup, not just in case of accidental data loss, but because we as geeks like data portability and would prefer to be able to export the whole profile in a machine readable format - which we can either re-import later, or simply just keep somewhere safe!

Answer (score 1):

I think that this would be a nice addition, but I would take it a small step further.  Why not allow the *importing* of pdf copies of our resume which we've exported?

Comment: I see _export and re-import_. Option like that would be convenient to me - thanks for idea. As for pdf resume, backup-wise it seems compromised don't you think? I mean, it doesn't cover Stack Exchange, Writing, Reading sections - in my case that's quite a lot of important stuff.